# Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am new to `Android`, I followed some tutorials online to create a login page with `MySQL` database hosted locally on my PC.

I am getting an error on `JSONParser.java` file says:

Error:(60, 61) error: incompatible types: `List<Pair<String,String>> cannot be converted to List<? extends NameValuePair>`

Here is the code in JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {...}

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<Pair<String, String>> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And here is for Login.java

```
public class login extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputUsername, inputPassword;
    Button btnlogin;
    TextView txtregister;

    // url to login
    private static String url_login = "http://10.0.2.2/VICOBA/login.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Edit Text
        inputUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        inputPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        //Text View
        txtregister = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.createAccount);

        //Create button
        btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Make login in background thread
                String username = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                new doLogin().execute(username,password);
            }
        });

    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class doLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
            String username = args[0];
            String password = args[1];

            // Building parameters
            List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new Pair<>("username", username));
            params.add(new Pair<>("password", password));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login,
            "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Login", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I have stacked here for some days trying searching for online solution with no success.

Comment: which line u getting error?

Comment: `Pair<String, String>` is not the same thing as `NameValuePair`.

Comment: Thank you Mike, how do I resolve this?

Comment: I am also getting error on checking for request method by using  DefaultHttpClient  and in UrlEncodedFormEntity, they are saying deprecated

Comment: Debug code and research type conversion errors.